# Combine range and match in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have documents in an Elasticsearch index with the following structure:

```
{
  "title": 'Nutrtional facts',
  "begin_timestamp" : 1582686052,
  "end_timestamp" : 1582686093
}

{
  "title": 'Guitar facts',
  "begin_timestamp" : 1447991100,
  "end_timestamp" : 1447994100
}

{
  "title": 'Hair style facts',
  "begin_timestamp" : 1447991100,
  "end_timestamp" : 1447994100
}

{
  "title": 'Piano facts',
  "begin_timestamp" : 1554416211,
  "end_timestamp" : 1591308724
}
```

I am aiming to retrieve documents where the title matches `facts` and if either the begin or end timestamp is greater than the current date and time.

```
title matches `facts` && begin_timestamp > CURRENT_DATE_TIME OR end_timestamp > CURRENT_DATE_TIME
```

The current query I am running is as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "facts"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "begin_timestamp_for_search": {
              "gte": 1580853917
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "begin_timestamp_for_search": {
              "gte": 1580853917
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This however is matching anything that matches `facts`,  and returning all documents regardless of the timestamps being before or after the current date and time.  I am fairly new to ES and wondering how I would write a query so the only documents that would come back is:

```
{
  "title": 'Nutrtional facts',
  "begin_timestamp" : 1582686052,
  "end_timestamp" : 1582686093
}

{
  "title": 'Piano facts',
  "begin_timestamp" : 1570227141,
  "end_timestamp" : 1591308724
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some small typos in your code snippets and you need to wrap your `should`-clause into another `bool`-query which you add/move to into your must clause.

**Solution** (verified with ES 7.5.x)

```
POST my_index/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Nutrtional facts", "begin_timestamp": 1582686052, "end_timestamp": 1582686093}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Guitar facts", "begin_timestamp": 1447991100, "end_timestamp": 1447994100}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Hair style facts", "begin_timestamp": 1447991100, "end_timestamp": 1447994100}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Piano facts", "begin_timestamp": 1554416211, "end_timestamp": 1591308724}


GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"title": "facts"}},
        {"bool": {
          "should": [
            {"range": {"begin_timestamp": {"gte": 1580853917}}},
            {"range": {"end_timestamp": {"gte": 1580853917}}}
          ]
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Comment 1:** The code above solution snippet fixes the typos in your code fragments:

- using different field-names in the documents and in the query
- querying both times against the same `begin_timestamp`-field

**Comment 2:** `"minimum_should_match": 1` is not required as this is the default behavior of a `bool`-query only made up of `should`-clauses.

**Tipp**: it's best to model your timestamps as fields of type `date`. That allows you to use date math (e.g. `now` in your queries). Internally Elasticsearch will store your dates as epoch_in_millis.

Comment: Thanks!  I have updated my dates mapping.  This works great!

Comment: Your `Comment 2` is not correct. The documentation says that "If the bool query includes at least one should clause and no must or filter clauses, the default value is 1. Otherwise, the default value is 0."  Which is exactly why I suggested to set it to 1. I still think that is more readable and performant using `minimum_should_match` rather than defining nested boolean queries. Anyway, your solution works just fine :)

Comment: I was referring to the nested, inner boolean query, which is only made up of should clauses. In that particular scenario Elasticsearch will require at least one of the should clauses to much, making it equivalent to explicitly setting `minimum_should_match` to 1. It may be good/better for readability, but it is not required here. If a `bool`-query contains a query in a non-should clause, then the default value of `minimum_should_match` is - as you state - 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "wildcard": {
                                                "title": {
                                                    "wildcard": "*facts*",
                                                    "boost": 1
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "should": [
                                                    {
                                                        "range": {
                                                            "begin_timestamp": {
                                                                "from": 1580853917,
                                                                "to": null,
                                                                "include_lower": false,
                                                                "include_upper": true,
                                                                "boost": 1
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "range": {
                                                            "end_timestamp": {
                                                                "from": 1580853917,
                                                                "to": null,
                                                                "include_lower": false,
                                                                "include_upper": true,
                                                                "boost": 1
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                                                "boost": 1
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                                    "boost": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your query has some wrong names - e.g., `begin_timestamp_for_search` should be `begin_timestamp` according to your documents
2. You need to set the `minimum_should_match` option to 1 for requiring that at least one `should` condition is matched ([link to Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match))

Therefore, your query should look something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "facts"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "begin_timestamp": {
              "gte": 1580853917
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "end_timestamp": {
              "gte": 1580853917
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```